# What is the origin of "ghem"?

Tags: vorkosigan-saga, lois-mcmaster-bujold

In the Cetagandan Empire of Lois McMaster Bujold's Vorkosigan saga, there are at least three named classes:

- The haut (the sequestered ruling class)
- The ba (their servants)
- The ghem (military leaders and administrators)

"Haut" and "ba" are obviously derived from the French words for "high" and "low."

**Is there a similar derivation for "ghem," or is it a nonsense syllable?**

Comment: Word of God answer is that it's meaningless. Case closed, Micah :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Word of God answer from Bujold's on her [own forum](http://bar.baen.com/index.php?t=msg&th=104921&goto=1003866&#msg_1003866) is that it's a made-up word with no deep etymological meaning.

[image: Bujold Quiote]

Comment: This appears to be behind some kind of gateway and doesn't directly relate to the names chosen. Clearly Haut and Ba have an easy-to-decipher meaning

Comment: Ah. It goes to the Baen's Bar forums. The quote above was from Lois McMaster Bujold, as can be seen by anyone with a (free) login. Other than that, I'm not certain what more to add...

Comment: I'm just thinking that her quote ignores the fact that quite a few names in her books clearly do have meanings...

Comment: {nods} She did not comment on us getting the others "right". I didn't ask further because she seemed kind of annoyed at the question.

Answer (score 0):

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ghem) offers two translations from the Romanian. The first meaning, "ball of thread or yarn", does not seem especially pertinent, although a saga is a kind of yarn. The second meaning, "**third compartment** of a ruminant's stomach", could make some kind of metaphorical sense.

Comment: Also means 'a midnight snack' in Klingon.

Answer (score 0):

I had always read that as alluding to *gems*. Since the ghem, like the haut, tend to be beautiful, long lived and just all around improved humans (at least according to the ghem), I simply read *ghem lords* as evocative of diamonds and pretty shiny things. Something further supported by their fondness for face painting.

I can find no canon reference to back this up. I *did*, however, find [this](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?root=config&morpho=0&basename=%5Cdata%5Cie%5Cpiet&first=861):

> Proto-IE: *ghem- 
>   Meaning: earth 
>   Hittite: gim(ma)ra- c. 'Feld, Flur' Tischler 573 f 
>   Old Indian: gen. gmá-ḥ (as if from kṣā́ḥ, see *dg'hem-) 
>   Old Greek: khamái̯ `zur Erde hin, auf der Erde' 
>   Russ. meaning: земля 
>   References: WP I 662 f, Buck 16 
>   Comments: Hard to distinguish from the reflexes of the widely spread *dg'hem- #395. All Italic forms (Lat humus, etc.) may in fact belong here.

So, `ghem` is actually a [proto-indo-european](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language) root meaning *earth*. I have no idea if Ms Bujold's erudition extends to PIE roots (though I would not put it past her) but if so, this lends some support to my theory linking *ghem* to *gem*.

Still, in the absence of any canon support this does seem a bit of a stretch, but you never know. I can confirm (since I happen to speak it) that the Greek that is sprinkled around the Vorkosigan books is actual Greek and so, presumably, is the Russian. You've already pointed out the French connection so it does not seem to far-fetched to assume that Bujold is a language geek and might even be aware of the meaning I list above.

Comment: Dare I suggest that your first suspicion was influence by the traditional fannish insertion of the letter “h,”e.g., “bheer” in http://www.cherryh.com/www/fiawol.htm?

Comment: @FlashSheridan nope, I'm afraid I have never heard of that convention. In fact, I don't think I've ever read any fan fiction at all.